# Block USB mass Storge or USB Port programmatically?

Tags: android

I am working on Device Administrator application,As per requirement I have to block the USB port or USB Storage to prevent device communication through USB.Is it possible to do with Java code? -please share me any sample code or Docs.

Answer (score 0):

It's a possibility to:

Add a usb intent filter on your app.

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
</intent-filter>
```

In your app intent method pick up the UsbDevice, then get its UsbDeviceConnection object and close() it.

I don't know if it works, but that's what i would try looking at the docs.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html

There are probably cleaner methods then this, but you could try it.